# Get data related to a user from sqlite after a successful login android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a user table in sqlite in my android app. The columns in the table are:

- id
- name
- username
- email
- age
- amount
- password

I am able to login in successfully with the person's email and password, and I use intent to pass the email to the dashboard activity. How do i query the the database to show the person's name, username, age and amount and pass that to different textviews?

Here is my User class

```
public class User {

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String username;
    public String email;
    public String password;
    public String age;
    public  String amount;

    public User (int id, String name, String username, String email, String age, String amount, String password){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getId(){ return id; }
    public String getName(){ return name; }
    public String getUsername(){ return username; }
    public String getEmail(){return email; }
    public String getAge(){ return age; }
    public String getAmount(){ return amount; }
    public String getPassword() {return password; }



}
```

Here is my getData method in SQLiteHelper class

```
  public String getData(int id, String name, String username, String email, String age, String amount, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from users where email='" + email + "'", null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
            User response = new User(id, name, username, email, age, amount, password);
            response.email = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(Table_Column_2_Email));
            response.name = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(Table_Column_1_Name));
            response.username = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(Table_Column_1_Username));
            response.age = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(Table_Column_3_Age));
            response.amount = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(Table_Column_3_Amount));
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Now how do I get the data for the loggin user and pass it to a textview in my Dashboard activity? I have some few years experience in Android development, but I have almost no experience in sqlite. I am sure the answer is simple but I have not been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

maybe just create some custom class

```
public class User {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String username;
    public String email;
    public int age;
    public int amount;
    public String password;
}
```

and instead of returning `String response` return `new User` fulfiled with data from cursor

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("select * from users where email='" + email + "'", null);
res.moveToFirst();
while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
    User response = new User();
    response.email = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(Table_Column_2_Email));
    // rest of columns
    return response;
}
return null;
```

you can also make `User` `implements Parcelabe` and pass it straight to new `Activity` using `Intent`/`Bundle` (some doc in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles))

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have added improved my code, but I am still not there yet, if you will permit me, let me modify the changes to reflect my improved code.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend you use the id of the user as parameter for `getData()` as far as that's possible as an id is very likely to be a primary key.

If you ask the database to return everything from the user with the passed id and the entry for email is `null` then your query would just return `null`. The `id`as primary key will never be `null`.

But if you ask it to return everything from a user, with the passed email and that email is not in the table, the database would throw an error which would be much more difficult to handle on android side.

Give that you can try the following:

```
public String getData(String id) {

    String response = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * 
         FROM users
         WHERE id = " + id + ";", null
    );
    res.moveToFirst();
    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        response += (res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(Table_Column_2_Email)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return response;
}
```

While doing so I would also recommend that you simulatenously create a User object like [snachmsm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65214670/7616822) suggested. Also for learning purposes,let the `response` be logged into the console as it returns from the database to create the constructor of the User class correctly.

Comment: Dont get confused by the type coloration, there something odd there ...

Comment: Hi, I have done as you suggested and have updated my question. now I am not able to show the data on the dashboard

Comment: What does it show indeed? Or do you get any other error messages?

Comment: No I don't get any error message. I want to get the values in my Dashboard activity. I am not sure what to do there.

Comment: Hi, I have made some headway, I am able to get the value and log it to the console, for example, I am able to get response.amount and Log it to console. Now how to access this value in Dashboard class is my problem. I tried using the User class I created with it's methods getAmount. But honestly I am not sure what I am doing

Comment: thats no big problem, we all start somewhere. can you maybe provide a sample code, where you want to display the users email and maybe maybe (if that isnt too much effort) a screenshot of where the mail should be displayed? Layouting activities can be very complex and I step into one or the other trap too in my android times